# Is there a way to get a popup confirmation box when you send an email in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I use two email accounts under Thunderbird (my personal email and my work email). But when I write a new email I always forget to check which one it's sending from, and sometimes end up sending an email from the wrong account. When I hit `Send` I'd like to see a little popup confirmation box that tells me to check my sending address before it actually sends, with a cancel button if it's the wrong address. Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Thunderbird here to test it, but this add-on here might be one that (almost) does what you're looking for:
[Check and Send](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/2281/)

Here's another one: [Any Confirmation Message](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/11287/)

Comment: Any Confirmation Message is precisely what I needed. Thanks!